# How to switch launcher activity while the application is running

Tags: java, android-activity, android-manifest, intentfilter, android-launcher

I have an application that has two main activities MainActivity1 and MainActivity2.
I have the Intent filter for the launcher on MainActivity1

```
       activity android:name=".MainActivity1">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

what I want is to be able to switch the launcher activity in my settings activity.
Is that possible and how will it work?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Please explain the reason you want to do this.

Comment: I have an app with two main activities and I want the users to have a choice on which one they want to see first

Answer (score 0):

All I did was to create a shared preference boolean the know which activity to open. Then from MainActivity1 I used an intent to go to MainActivity2

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    boolean firstTimeOpening = intent.getBooleanExtra("BOOLEAN_FIRST_TIME_OPENING", true);

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("SHARED_PREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean startAppWithActivity1 = preferences.getBoolean(START_APP_WITH_ACTIVITY1, true);
    if(!startAppWithActivity1 && firstTimeOpening){ startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity1.this, MainActivity2.class));
```

}

Easy enough. The firstTimeOpening boolean makes sure the the switching
of activity occurs only when the application is just opened

Comment: This is a better approach to solving the problem.